# Loopback vs NIC path

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-adapter

I'm trying to troubleshoot a complex problem in my computer running Windows 7. I won't describe the problem as it would take a very long time to explain.
Basically I'm running a software that connect to another software via the network. I can either choose to run this program on my main machine and have it connect via the loopback or run it on my other computers. 
Running this program on my main machine with it connecting via the loopback works perfectly while running it to another computer using the network isn't working very well. 
I'd like to know how a loopback connection differs from a connection to the NIC. Is there any difference once the data reaches the processor? Is it possible that one has a higher priority that the other? Is it possible for another computer component (possibly graphics) interfere with one but not the other? OR is the only difference that one uses the driver for the NIC indicating that my issues HAVE to be a result of the driver?

Comment: Hmm "I won't describe the problem" doesn't help us to help you ...

Comment: This is something that I've spent 6 months troubleshooting and speaking with the support of multiple companies trying to sort out so trying to explain it would take quite a bit of time and I'm not looking for someone here to try to solve the problem. I'd just like to know how the loopback connection relates to the NIC connection to know if the only possible issue is the NIC driver or if there could be something else happening at the processor after the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe more detailed what you mean with "isn't working very well"? Maybe it is because traffic to the NIC is going to the firewall, while traffic to loopback is not?

Comment: The traffic is arriving at the NIC properly and turning off the firewall doesn't make a difference. Also, there's no anti virus on the computer. It seems to be something to do with latency not allowing the data from the network instances to arrive quick enough. I feel like something else is taking priority and the data from the NIC is taking longer to process. If the NIC and the loopback both arrive at the processor the same way then there's no reason that one if working perfectly and the other isn't so then I think it would mean that the issue can't be related to the interrupts.

Comment: The program streams audio in realtime and there are pops and clicks in the network instances while the instances which run on the computer which also runs the application that the audio gets streamed to works perfectly.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

Just a clarification on loopback: Packets sent through 127.0.0.x [there are multiple loopback addresses, which I've used to handle separate traffic] never reach the network card. 
" It is implemented entirely within the operating system's networking software and passes no packets to any network interface controller." from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback.
Sorry if I've restated what you already know.